# How do I get the polynomial regression coefficients using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, regression, vba

I have two columns, say `x` and `f(x)`. I want to get the coefficients of the second degree equation after doing the polynomial regression in Excel VBA.

I'm a rookie in Excel VBA and have no clue what to do.

For example-

> x y
>   -1 -1
>   0 3
>   1 2.5
>   2 5
>   3 4
>   5 2
>   7 5
>   9 4

The coefficients for the equation `f(x)=a*x^2+b*x+c` will be

```
a= -.008571
b= 0.99555
c= 1.648439.
```

I got the coefficients using [THIS](http://www.arachnoid.com/polysolve/) website

Comment: You may be a newbie in Excel VBA, but how would you solve it formula wise?

Comment: I could use the LINEST function, but the coefficients got from that function differs from the coefficients got from the http://www.arachnoid.com/polysolve/ website. So, I'm not sure about using the function.

Comment: If you had say 1,9,5,7 in A1:A4 and 0,4,2,3 in B1:B4, What result are you expecting? `1-0,2-2,3-1`?

Comment: No. The equation will read as f(x) = 0*x^2+0.5*x-0.5

Result: 0, 0.5 & -0.5

Comment: hmmm. I am getting `-0.03`, `1.11`, `0.22`. Lemme check it again.

Comment: Raul - i get agreement to 15sf in coefficients `-0.085717636022514*x^2 +0.995557119032729*x +1.64843912862205` with the Linest formula given in Brett's response. If results differ with large amounts of data, i would trust the (QR) Linest method to be more numerically stable than the (normal equation) method given in the website link.

Comment: @lori_m but I checked on two websites and the coefficients from the websites were same, but the LINEST function gave a little different values and that was a large data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of using code for this, use `LINEST`, one way below

```
Sub Quaddy()
Dim X
X = Application.Evaluate("=linest(b1:B8,A1:A8^{1,2})")
MsgBox "Equation is y=" & Format(X(1), "0.###") & "x2+" & Format(X(2), "0.###") & "x+" & Format(X(3), "0.###")
End Sub
```

This is shown in the Excel chart below
[image]

Comment: Thank you, @brettdj. The problem with the linest function is when the data is huge. As I mentioned earlier, the coefficients are not accurate when using LINEST function because I cross checked it on different websites of polynomial regression for the coefficients and the websites gave the same result, but Excel gave slightly different values.

Comment: +1. Or use: `Application.LinEst(y, Application.Power(x, Array(1, 2)))`

Comment: @SiddharthRout looking up against that new question? :)

Comment: Yup :) I thought I saw a similar question. Wanted to close it as duplicate but couldn't find it:D

Comment: Nice answer @brettdj - For anyone else looking for way to do higher order such as 4th degree change the array like this: `^{1,2,3,4}` - surprising how many 'how to' references don't explain that part of `LINEST()`